# Changing table field using 2 different models

Tags: cakephp

I have an IT query system were by users can add their queries, when they add their query the IT department then replies/comments on the query.

How is should work is when the user adds a query it must change the query_type field in the it_queries table to OPEN and when the IT department views the query they reply/comment on it and must change query_type field from OPEN to PENDING then finally when the user has been helped/assisted they should be able to mark the query as closed using a checkbox, that will then change the status from PENDING TO CLOSE.

Not sure if they is a way of setting the constants in the add views and insert in the table.

Obviously i am learning and can someone please guide me on the steps i must take.

Here is my code for the add it_query for the users

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQuery'); ?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?php echo __('Add It Query'); ?></legend>
<?php
echo $this->Form->hidden('hr_employee_id',array('value'=>$loggedInId));
echo $this->Form->input('it_query_type_id');
echo $this->Form->input('comment');
echo $this->Form->hidden('status_type', array('value'=>OPEN));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Here is the code for my comments for IT Department

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('ItQueryComment'); ?>

<?php echo __('Add It Query Comment'); ?>
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('it_query_id');
echo $this->Form->input('comment');
echo $this->Form->input('close_query');
?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Here is the code for my ItQueryComments

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
$this->ItQueryComment->create();
if ($this->ItQueryComment->save($this->request->data)) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query comment has been saved'));
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'it_queries','action' => 'view', $this->request->data['ItQueryComment']['it_query_id']));
} else {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The it query comment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
}
$itQueries = $this->ItQueryComment->ItQuery->find('list');
$hrEmployees = $this->ItQueryComment->HrEmployee->find('list');
$this->set(compact('itQueries', 'hrEmployees'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While saving a comment for a particular Itquery , in your add function of Comments Controller after adding comment to database get its id by using $this->getLastInsertID();
 and call function updateAll for Itquery Model and change status of that particular Query to "Pending".

Comment: I am new to cakephp, i have added the controller code. Can you please highlight where i must update the code?